# Avg rate of change help?

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this please?
Thank You:

Let $()=−4^2+4$

Find an expression for the average rate of change of  over the interval $[,+ℎ]$

Comment: What is the formula for the average rate of change?

Comment: Remember what "rate of change of $f$" means. It is the change in $f(x)$ values divided by the change in $x$ values

Comment: Hint: Average rate of change in $[a,b]=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Answer (score 2):

The [avg rate](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:functions/x2f8bb11595b61c86:average-rate-of-change-word-problems/a/average-rate-of-change-review)  of that function is
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{-4(x^2+h^2+2xh)+4(x+h)+4x^2-4x}{h}=\frac{-4h^2-8xh+4h}{h}=-4h-8x+4$$
And it's correct infact we have that for $h$ tends to $0$ avg rate tends to the derivative of $f(x)$

Comment: Thank you, but my online checker says this is incorrect?

Comment: and which should be the result? @newtoJAVA

Comment: @newtoJAVA, if you have another answer post it. This answer looks correct.

Comment: you're right, I'll change it, thanks @NoChance